# Can someone edit this image for me?

Tags: photo-editing

So I have this image:

https://ugc.kn3.net/i/origin/http://www.loaditup.de/files/430044.png

My friend wants it to say:

`Pimp My Level`

in the same text as the image above, if you can do this for me I would appreciate it!

Just link the image below, I will upvvote and accept the first person to do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a free graphic design service

Comment: How much are you willing to pay for this service?

Comment: Tell you what, looks like you've been over to CodeReview.SE...I'll do your PS work if you build a couple of web pages for me (AMPscript knowledge required). So, how 'bout it?

Comment: @user371376 There is a very specific reasoning to this site (and all sites in the Stack Exchange network). It is a "question and answer" site. Imagine a big photography-oriented "FAQ". This is not a forum for chatting, and certainly not a site for requesting free graphic design services - that's not even photography for a start. Because of this site's focus, your question is being bluntly received. If you actually have a photography question, you will receive expert help here.

Answer (score 5):

This belongs in the comments but I can't comment yet.

- You're not asking a question about photography.
- You're asking someone to do something for you.

But still here you go I found the font used by Pimp My Ride.

http://flexfonts.net/font/pimp-my-ride.html

You'll have to figure out the next steps by yourself.

Comment: You are far too kind

Comment: My understanding is that you get the "comment everywhere" privilege at 50 reputation points, so you should already have that.

Comment: At the time I posted this I didn't …